# Not able to access project deployed in Tomcat in another server in LAN

Tags: java, tomcat

I have developed a project and its running fine in local. I have created a war file and deployed it there and tested in server itself as localhost. It works fine. When I try to point from my machine as `http://<server ip>:8080/<project name>`, its not able to connect.

All it says

```
This site can’t be reached

<server ip> took too long to respond.
```

I tried to check whether I'm able to ping

```
ping <ip address>
```

Its able to connect.

What other configuration is required to connect to the project from my local system browser that is deployed in the server machine?

Comment: Have you checked the tomcat logs? (access/catalina/localhost) to see if your request is reaching the server?

Comment: Might be the server's firewall blocking incoming connections on port 8080. Have you checked the firewall configuration?

Comment: @BalázsNemes , let me check